# A sequence of polynomials with degree going to $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(\mathcal p_n)$ be a sequence of polynomials which converges uniformly on $[0,1]$ to some function $\mathcal f$, assume that $\mathcal f$ is not a polynomial. Prove the $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\deg(\mathcal p_n)=\infty,$ where deg$(\mathcal p)$ denotes the degree of a polynomial $\mathcal p$.

It is well known that space of polynomials is dense in the space of continuous functions. Intuition,If the degree of polynomial is finite then space of polynomial would be closed which no longer dense in the space of $C[0,1]$. Is it correct intuition? Give me ideas.

Comment: Your title does not make sense: a polynomial has a degree (if it is not the zero poynomial) and that degree **always** is a natural number.

Comment: Would the folks voting to close care to share their reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, suppose that all your polynomials have degree at most $d$. Then the subspace $S$ of $C[0,1]$ of polynomials of degree at most $d$ is *closed* (as is any other finite dimensional subspace, for that matter), so any sequence contained in $S$ which converges in $C[0,1]$ has limit in $S$.

Comment: Thanks, that means my intuition is correct. I was also thinking same as you did but i was not sure, you made me sure.